# How to process a binary image to align sparse letters in a row?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use tesseract ocr to convert an image to text. The image always have three letters without rotation/skew, but randomly distributed in an 90x50 png file.

By just cleaning and converting to black/white, tesseract could not get the text in the image. After aligning them by hand in Paint, the ocr gives the exact match. I doesn't even need to be exactly aligned.
What I want is some tips on how to automate this alignment of the characters in the image prior to sending it to tesseract.

I am using python with tesseract and opencv.

Original image:
[image: origional image]

What I have done - turn black and white:
[image: What I have done - turn black and white]

What I want to do - aligned by code:
[image: What I want to do - aligned by code]

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Here's the steps I would do to obtain your desired result. Threshold image to remove background which should result in what you have in the 2nd image. Then create a blank white image using Numpy. Next find bounding boxes for each letter and crop the ROIs onto the blank white image.

Comment: @AustenHolland , Thanks! I'm new here. I had made the code to convert the first into the second image, but what i was actually looking for was an answer as the one given by nathancy . I will read the FAQ and keep your tips in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: letters]

You can use the following code to achieve this output. Some of the constants may need to be changed to fit your needs:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read the image (resize so it is easier to see)
img = cv2.imread("/home/stephen/Desktop/letters.png",0)
h,w = img.shape
img = cv2.resize(img, (w*5,h*5))
# Threshold the image and find the contours
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 123, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Create a white background iamge to paste the letters on
bg = np.zeros((200,200), np.uint8)
bg[:] = 255
left = 5

# Iterate through the contours
for contour,h in zip(contours, hierarchy[0]):
    # Ignore inside parts (circle in a 'p' or 'b')
    if h[3] == -1:
        # Get the bounding rectangle
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        # Paste it onto the background
        bg[5:5+h,left:left+w] = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        left += (w + 5)
cv2.imshow('thresh', bg)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: This code was almost perfect for what i intended. I had to tweak it for it to look for the letters from left to right, instead of bottom up. For some reason, changing the order of threshold/resize made the OCR get more right results after the preprocessing.